# unable to run requests for flask on internal server

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Running a server on

```
> http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

and trying to do a post request (the actual code is a bit more complicated but this is the part I cannot get working). Basically, trying to get something like the following to work but this returns and error saying its not found.

```
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/user')
```

I also tried something like the following but it returns:

```
url = url_for('api.userlistapi')
payload = {'email':email, 'password':password,'profile_verified':False}
r = requests.post(url)

self.prepare_url(url, params)
File "....appp/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 360, in prepare_url
"Perhaps you meant http://{0}?".format(url))
MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'/api/user': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///api/user?
```

Any help would be appreciated! It might just be something dumb with routing or that a post request should be done differntly? I am also using angular and those requests to the same domain work.

Comment: Issue was fixed. See response below from Jivan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right tracks with the second solution you tested.

You just have to add `_external=True` to `url_for` arguments:

```
url = url_for('api.userlistapi', _external=True)
payload = {'email':email, 'password':password,'profile_verified':False}
r = requests.post(url)
```

This way, Flask is able to construct a full `url` with domain included. Otherwise, `url_for` only builds a relative `url` meant to be called from within your domain.

--

Also, as a side note, you can pass your parameters directly with `requests` the following way:

```
r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
```

But it depends on other factors in the rest of your code, based on what you want to do.

Comment: File "XXXXXXX/hubbub/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 303, in prepare
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this frameself.prepare_url(url, params)
File "XXXXXXXXXX/hubbub/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 360, in prepare_url
"Perhaps you meant http://{0}?".format(url))
MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'/api/user?external=True': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///api/user?external=True?             I still get the following error when I change the code to

Comment: url = url_for('api.userlistapi', external=True)
            payload = {'email':email, 'password':password,'profile_verified':False}
            r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))          Thanks a lot for the response by the way

Comment: So that sort of works, it then leads to a page that is in loading state forever. This should not be the case given that the payload is very small/even if I remove the payload it does not work. I tried the post request to some other websites and those all work fine. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't make requests to the development server using the development server. It can only handle one synchronous request at a time.

Comment: Got it thats what I thought... is there a easy work around for this?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do exactly, but either you have all the informations and could do all treatment during the scope of the current requests, or you could perhaps use javascript and make an ajax request from your front. Depends on what your needs are and how your app is structured.